# Inserting into Hive Table error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am looking to encode columns of a table in hive.

I tried:

```
hive> create table encode_test(id int, name STRING, phone STRING, address STRING) 
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('column.encode.columns'='phone,address', 'column.encode.classname'='org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.Base64WriteOnly') STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Say i have a CSV file, with following row

```
100,'navis','010-0000-0000','Seoul Seocho'
```

Now i tried to use.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH
'/home/path/to/csv/test.csv'
INTO TABLE encode_test;
```

But when doing `Select * from encode_test i am getting all columns NULL`

Whereas the result should have been

`100    navis     MDEwLTAwMDAtMDAwMA==  U2VvdWwsIFNlb2Nobw==`

Also i want to give  `Fields TERMINATED BY ','` IN create table encode_test query.

but i am getting `error:  EOF error Near Fields`

I also tried creating another table `sample`

`create table sample(id int, name STRING, phone STRING, address STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;`

And then imported the csv file in the `sample` table. and it was successfully imported.

then i tried using.

`insert into encode_test select * from sample;`

But i am getting this new error 
`Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user":h                                                                                        dfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.c                                                                                        heckFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:279)`

I'n new into hadoop

Please refer to [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6329) from where i tried this problem

Comment: Run the hive query as either `hdfs` or `hive` user!

Comment: @franklinsijo and why can't is use `fields terminated by ','  when im using row format serde` since data  is in csv

Comment: check if the answer suits.. I am not able to check the encode part though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive [DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable), `ROW FORMAT SERDE` and `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` cannot co-exist together. Instead you can use, `field.delim` serde property.

```
create table encode_test(id int, name STRING, phone STRING, address STRING) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
             'field.delim'=',',
             'column.encode.columns'='phone,address',
             'column.encode.classname'='org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.Base64WriteOnly')     
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

And for the `PermissionDenied` exception, run the hive queries as either `hdfs` or `hive` user since `root` user does not have `WRITE` access to HDFS.

Comment: i tried running the queries as hdfs.
But when i queried `INSERT INTO TABLE  encode_test select * from sample;`

I got the following error

Comment: `Starting Job = job_1488189133306_0004, Tracking URL = http://xxx.xxx:8088/proxy/application_1488189133306_0004/
Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.10.0-1.cdh5.10.0.p0.41/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1488189133306_0004
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2017-02-27 02:08:58,787 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1488189133306_0004 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask`

Comment: Is this the entire stacktrace? If yes, check for the Yarn logs. Failure of a mapreduce task could be due to many number of causes. Need more info to debug

Comment: Also I assume that the field terminated by problem is solved!

Comment: its just a part of the error, it was too long to post here.

`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
`

Comment: Post it any pastebin and share the link here! Or you can post a new question on it!\

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/sdd0li/9  or https://img42.com/Q1ek6  take a look at the error

Comment: Should I join to view the content? I am unable to see any~!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-k7z2Y5a9rEcjlFeDF1bmktVlk/view?usp=sharing  try this link sir

Comment: Can you please check the corresponding yarn log. This does not provide any valuable information. You should be able to locate the log in resourcemanager UI.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-k7z2Y5a9rEYUtNZ25lZEhnYjg/view?usp=sharing Check the logs

Comment: Is your cluster kerberized? Either the nodes are running at with different time or the tokens are invalid.

Comment: Sir, i just wanted to encrypt columns of a table while dumping it into hdfs, as a part of my assignment, so i was working on the method given here  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6329 , i am new to hadoop

Comment: I understand that, the issue you are facing now is beyond the scope of this question. I would suggest you to search for issues relating to "Yarn Exception: unauthorized request to start container". This is an authorization problem related to hadoop, not hive.